# How to remove a many-to-many relationship based on the Pivot Table information

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am in need to detach records from my pivot table, based on info stored in it.

So I have three tables, 1) Activity 2) activity_submissions 3) Submissions

One activity can have many submissions and one submission can have many activities, they share a many to many relationship. Now there is a catch: the activity_submissions table has a description column in it too.

This is the activity_submissions table:

```
id | activity_id | submission_id | desription
```

So I have three records as below:

```
1 | 20 | 1 | "First"
2 | 20 | 1 | "Second"
3 | 20 | 1 | "Third"
```

I only want to reove the one with description "Third".

I tried using detach, but that removes all of them:

```
$activity=\App\Activity::find(20);
$submissions=$activity->submissions()->where('submission_id','=','1')->get();
for($i=0; $i<$submissions->count(); $i++){
    if ($submissions[$i]->pivot->description == "Third"){
       $submissions[$i]->activities()->detach();
    }
}
```

But this code detaches all my records, how would I go about doing this? I am using Laravel 5.0.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `->wherePivot()` function to filter out pivot table.

```
$submissions[$i]->activities()->wherePivot('description', '=', $yourVal)->detach();
```

In your case `$yourVal = "Third";`